# Using jQuery Date picker with a custom trigger button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How do I make the jQuery Datepicker open up by a user defined button?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's [built-in support for this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger), having an icon or button to right right of the textbox, like this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  showOn: 'button',
  buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
  buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

If you want to show it from *another* button, or really any event, call the [`show` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-show), like this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
});
```

[You can try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ehVM/)

Comment: @pvaju896 - Nope...how are you calling it? Keep in mind that in a user control the ID will be different, you should use classes instead

Comment: you meant JQUERY classes..?? am new to JQUERY..

how can i set class so..?/?? i made user control with just a textbox registered to aspx page and called the usercontrol..

i tried giving datepicker for that usercontrol textbox --> it dint wrk  dats y..??

wat should i do now..?/ how to do with classes??

Comment: @pvaju896 in my control I keep data-target attribute in my button to tell me which input to target. SO as you are generating the control you can pass the clientID to javascript.

Comment: use `buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>"` instead if you want the fontawesome icon. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24021111/3380951

Answer (score 3):

I have solved using focus.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();

$("#myButton").click(function() {
 $("#datepicker").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The samples page as an example of how to make the datpicker appear by clicking an icon:

[here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

Answer (score 1):

This is HTML for date picker icon

```
onclick="show_date_picker('#datepicker_id');  on you icon element
```

This is function for open & close datepicker on icon click

```
function show_date_picker(source_datepicker){
    if($(source_datepicker).datepicker("widget").is(":visible")){
        $(source_datepicker).datepicker("hide");
    }else{ 
        $(source_datepicker).datepicker("show"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#checkin").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  minDate: '0',
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1
 });
```

```css
.datedivmng{
    float: left;position: relative;
}
.datedivmng .datepicker{
    position: relative;width: 87%!important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.datedivmng:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f073";
    color: #329ac4;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-shadow: none;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    pointer-events: none;
    float: right;
    top: 2px;
    right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="datedivmng">
  <input type="text" id="checkin" name="checkin"  value="" /></div>
```

Comment: JSfiddle link : jsfiddle.net/jrpatel1016/44hsdn4j

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear if you want an additional trigger or an additional trigger. If you want to have an additional trigger. The accepted answer did not work for me perhaps its an outdated version. The below code worked for me as a general trigger

```
    $('#datepicker').jqxDateTimeInput('open');
```