# jQuery Datepicker with FontAwesome Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, font-awesome

I'm building a site with Foundation, and I have the FontAwesome icons installed. I'm trying to set up a form where a user can click on an input or a button to see the jQuery datepicker. I'd like to be able to use the FontAwesome icon in the button. But I can't seem to get the button to trigger the datepicker.

**EDIT:**

I kind of got it working, but I still can't figure out how to implement the FontAwesome icon. I have this in my HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label>Departure Date</label>
        <div class="row date collapse">
        <div class="small-9 columns"><input class="small-9 columns" placeholder="Choose Date" type="text" name="date" id="date"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this in my JS:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "both", 
      buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
      buttonText: "THIS IS A BUTTON",
      buttonImageOnly: true
    });
  });
```

Where do I put the icon? Can I somehow put it in the `buttonText` argument?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add

```
buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>"
```

and add CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger{
    border:none;
    background:none;
 }
```

refer JSFiddler [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1894/).

Comment: Thanks but that fiddle doesn't have a button. I tried putting `buttonText: "<i class='icon-calendar'></i>"` in my JavaScript, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the updated link. I still can't get the icon to show. In my CSS, I put `.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    border:none;
    background: none;
}
` And in my JavaScript, I put `$(function() {
     $( "#departureDate" ).datepicker({
       showOn: "both", 
       buttonText: "<i class='fa icon-calendar'></i>"
     });
   });` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works in the fiddle, but it doesn't work on my site. Does that mean some CSS is interfering?

Comment: Yes, you had to use css class, fa fa-calendar, Great to know, you finally got it working, can you mark it answer. thanks.

Comment: How can we set calendar icon before textbox....?? It is adding calendar icon after textbox.

Comment: When I tried this. The final html is: &lt;i class='fa fa-calendar' aria-hidden='true'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;

Comment: Does this solution works with latest jquery version (13) ?

Answer (score 3):

With the help of @Ankit above, I finally got this working. In case anyone else is trying to do the same thing, here's the code that worked for me.

HTML

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label>Departure Date</label>
        <div class="row date collapse">
        <div class="small-9 columns"><input class="small-9 columns" placeholder="Choose Date" type="text" name="date" id="departureDate"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns">
        <label>Departure Date</label>
        <div class="row date collapse">
        <div class="small-9 columns"><input class="small-9 columns" placeholder="Choose Date" type="text" name="date" id="returnDate"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $( "#departureDate" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "both", 
      buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>"
    });
  });

$(function() {
    $( "#returnDate" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "both", 
      buttonText: "THIS IS A BUTTON!",
    });
  });
```

CSS

```
/* Datepicker Styles */

.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    border:none;
    background:none;
    float: right;
}

input.small-9.columns.hasDatepicker {
    float: left;
    width: 73%;
}

button.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    padding: 9px 14px;
}

button.ui-datepicker-trigger:hover {
    background: #CCC;
}

button.ui-datepicker-trigger i.fa.icon-calendar {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datepicker initialization needs to be in the document ready function...

```
$(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker();
    $( "#calButton" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "both", 
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `.calButton` instead of `#calButton` since you have set class on button not id.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".calButton" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "both", 
    });
});
```