# Font awesome icon in jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, font-awesome, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to display the fontawesome icon on "buttonText" of jquery date picker but it displays the text and not the icon. Is it correct? I am using jquery 13.

```
$("#btnDate").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>",
            onSelect: function (selected) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You may also want to review: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: @Twisty: i gave jquery code which i am trying. I am using buttontext as per this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019359/jquery-datepicker-with-fontawesome-button)

Comment: The onus is on you to create a snippet in your question that demonstrates your problem.  As it is, you've copied code from an existing question (without credit/reference) where it works.  If it's not working for you then there's some other part that you've missed/not done/done differently - that's the bit we need to see.  A *complete* snippet - including all `<script src=` and `<link href=` to show the issue.  Maybe you have the wrong versions in your scripts/css?

Comment: Specifically the classes `fa fa-calendar` will depend on the version of font-awesome and the `buttonText:` option will depend on the version of jquery-ui.   You've only stated "jquery 13" (1.3?)

Comment: @freedomn-m, i didn't just copy the code from other place. I tried on my side but it didn't work so i removed all extra code ( of my requirements) but still didn't work so i posted just the needed portion and it looked like copied version from other place and  it is "jquery-ui-1.13.1.js". Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the icon after setting the datepicker :

```js
$("#btnDate").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: "",
}).next('button').append('<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eTyxS0rkjpLEo16uXTS0uVCS4815lc40K2iVpWDvdSY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="btnDate"></p>
```

Comment: It does work on your snippet but doesn't work on my side. Even i added the style sheet url directly into my view but still the icon doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an incompatibility with using a Font Awesome image within an i tag for the Datepicker buttonText setting for jQuery UI 1.13.x.  It works fine with version 1.12.1.  I am using it with jQuery 3.5.1.

Here's my code:

```
$(".datepicker1").datepicker
({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar'></i>"
});
```

This is how it looks in version 1.12.1:

[Datepicker 1.12.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hIOf.png)

Here is how the same code looks when upgrading to 1.13.2:

[Datepicker 1.13.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omZzj.png)

So, a possible solution is to downgrade to jQuery UI 1.12.1 as it is still available on the jquery-ui site until there is a newer version where this will no longer be a problem.  The download site says it works with jQuery 1.7+, so you should not need to adjust your jQuery version.

By the way, Tom's answer did work for me using jQuery UI 1.13.2.  When I downloaded my copy of jQuery UI, I used the [Download Builder](https://jqueryui.com/download/) site and included the jQuery 1.8+ Support option.

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker created an element:

```
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" />
```

When you define the Text, it is added to the `alt` and `title` attributes. Like so:

```
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="Select date" title="Select date">
```

This is why your attempt is not working.

A `click` event is assigned to this that opens the datepicker. Since it's an image, you can't simply assign a Font Awesome Class to it.

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date"
  });

  var newButton = $("<span>", {
    class: "ui-datepicker-trigger fa fa-calendar"
  }).click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("closed");
    if ($(this).hasClass("closed")) {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
    } else {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker("hide");
    }
  });

  $("img.ui-datepicker-trigger").replaceWith(newButton);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Using `.replaceWith()` will do what you need to have done. It will not copy the `event`, so we have to recreate it.

Comment: *you can't simply assign a Font Awesome Class* - works fine on the question OP linked to:  http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/1894/  It's unclear why it's not working for OP, so maybe this approach will work for them

Comment: @freedomn-m it does, and that is using jQuery UI 1.8.16, which is creating a `button` element instead of an `img` element. This allows the Text to be wrapped inside the button and is rendered as HTML.

Comment: So OPs "*jquery 13*" is actually "jquery-ui 1.13"?  Would be nice if they were clearer.. :)

Comment: @freedomn-m I agree with you on that one. If we suspect that OP is using jQuery UI 1.3, his code does not work due to the `img` element.

Comment: I don't get img tag but i get below elements. **<input type="button" id="btnEndDate" class="btndatepicker hasDatepicker" value=""> <button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><i class='fa fa-calendar'></i></button>**

Comment: And i am using "jquery-2.1.0.js" and "jquery-ui-1.13.1.js".

Comment: @Hector Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example